# Is there a command is javascript that allows me to repeat a line of code a certain amount of times?

Tags: javascript

For example if I want to console log something "x" amount of times can i just input a command that will do exactly that? Continuously console log that statement the amount of times I specified? Thanks for your help in advance. I'm fairly new to javascript but thank you

Comment: Check the `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy to accomplish with a loop, the number in `i<n` let's you decide how often to log / how often to run the loop.

```
                    //    \/ make i incrementing with every loop 
 for (var i = 0;i < 20 ; i++){
 //   ^set var i  ^set number of loop runs
      console.log('hello');
   }
```